# Is it possible to hide a gutenberg block in wordpress search while still having it available for innerblock use?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm making a custom block plugin using wordpress create block (https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/02/28/new-wordpress-create-block-package-for-block-scaffolding/). And modified to contain two blocks using this approach https://dev.to/rmorse/how-to-create-a-multiple-block-plugin-for-wordpress-mpm.

So the plugin features two blocks, a parent that controls global settings and acts as a container, and a repeatable child block inside of it that has multiple instances.

I want users to only be able to access the parent block when searching and not the child block, but I don't want to *remove* the child block from the site, as it is part of the parent block.

I tried just hiding with css, but wordpress doesn't put classes on the outer most div when searching for blocks; so the best I was able to do with darken the child block and add an overlay with an :after to prevent clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more details? Your block was crated by using ACF or React?

//edit

```
registerBlockType( 'test/child-block', {
title: 'This is a Child Blcok',
// Only allow in a registered parent-block:
parent: [ 'test/parent-block' ],
});
```

or

```
<InnerBlocks
 allowedBlocks={ ALLOWED_BLOCKS }
 />
```

If you have still child block on list, you can try add this code

```
function remove_blocks_type($allowed_blocks){
    unset($allowed_blocks['test/child-block']);
    return $allowed_blocks;
}
add_filter('allowed_block_types', 'remove_blocks_type');
```

Comment: I edited my question. I'm using the wordpress create-block package, and then combining the two blocks into a single plugin.

Comment: @user3087958 Please check solution from edited comment.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tapne! This is perfect.